# Differentiate two markers at same place in Google maps

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google map with clusters of marker. When I have two same places only one marker is showing[one overlap other]. How can I differentiate two markers to make both visible?

[image]

Comment: When adding markers, if two are on the same coordinates, you could try offsetting one of them a few pixels?

Comment: how can we achieve this?

Comment: Spiderfy your markers - https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier

Comment: what is OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier in https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/blob/gh-pages/demo.html    ?

Comment: when i runs it getting script error OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier undefined